# missing_values not working with genfromtxt

Tags: python, csv, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to replace missing values from a csv file, which in my case are identified with a specific string. I'm doing this

```
data = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=',', autostrip=True, dtype=float, missing_values="ab", filling_values=0.0)
```

string `"ab"` is just an example, and it could be any string which I use to identify missing values. However, when I dump the csv to file, I see nan and not zero.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/15144352/3001761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug, as long as the `filling_value` is not `0` it will work `numpy 1.8.1`:

```
In [40]:

%%file temp.txt
1,2,3,4,ab
ab,1,2,2,4
Overwriting temp.txt
In [41]:

data = np.genfromtxt('temp.txt', delimiter=',', 
                     autostrip=True, dtype=float, missing_values="ab", filling_values=0.01)  
In [42]:

data
Out[42]:
array([[ 1.  ,  2.  ,  3.  ,  4.  ,  0.01],
       [ 0.01,  1.  ,  2.  ,  2.  ,  4.  ]])
```

Comment: the problem is that I really have to set them to zero. I guess I will do it by hand then.

Comment: I am using version 1.8.1

Comment: never mind, I did not notice the quote. now it works. thank you

Comment: The bug is now fixed in the development version: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/4968